# react native android app restarts when opened by clicking app icon (coming from background)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I open my app by clicking icon, do something and going to another component, pause the app by clicking home button.

If I open my app by clicking icon again, the app restarts and going first component.

If I open my app from recently open apps (in 4.0 by pressing menu button and selecting my app) it the app restarts and going first component.

I want the behavior 2 always to occur, don't want my app to restart every time when it is opened by clicking icon.

I want to my app restarting only one time (when app killed) and another time my app don't restart.

I searching many times in google and get some information and set but not working.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="...">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

my activity in manifest file is `android:launchMode="singleTop"` but not working for me! :(

my react native app information :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.3",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-is": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-highcharts": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "realm": "^10.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be so many things, I worked in a project where we were using so much memory of the device that when the user putted the app in background in just few seconds the app got killed, so it can be the memory usage of your app in the device. Take a look at this page in android docs. It talks about android backgroud processes with more details.

Comment: thanks dude for answer
but my problem when ram is free (no app in background and all apps closed) happened too !
this problem happened special device not all android device :(

Comment: But even when all apps are closed, your app can be killed too. When you run other apps in this "special" device, it gets killed in background too?  Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) of android, talking about background limits.

Comment: thanks my friend but i'm understand how to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace launchmode with `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your `MainActivity`